# Separate parts of long numbers in js code

Tags: javascript, numbers

Is it possible to separate parts of long numbers in js code?

E.g. is it possible to somehow separate parts of the `var n = 1000567234` to see the millions, thousands, hundreds and so on? I would expect to get something like this: `var n = 1.000.567.234` or `var n = 1,000,567,234` or any other (different from the `,`, `.`) separator.

While I would like the type of the data to remain number (and not convert it to a string).

I need this for the development easing purposes. It is easier to maintain, read and write the code which separates the number parts, since one can clearly see the number parts without processing (in head) the whole number.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString would this help? - Also look into [Numeric separators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Numeric_separators)

Comment: [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: I need the data type to remain number. Thank you.

Comment: You can't add seperators and keep the type as a number

Comment: you can use only `_` as the separator to keep it a number.

Comment: @AZ_, oh. That is exactly what I was expecting to find out. You saved my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't add separators and keep the type as a number.
you can add `_` in the number like `AZ_` said, but not all browsers support that (IE 11)...

Comment: Cool. This is useful.